# Почему скрипт сильно грузит CPU?

Tags: php

Смотрю в `htop` как 2 ядра по-очереди скачут от 16% до ~68%. Да, это парсинг, но все же может я как то не так написал?

```
require_once(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/simple_html_dom.php');

for ($i= 1; $i<=50; $i++){
    $id = $i;
    $post = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,lastupdate,gp FROM app WHERE id = ?');
    $post->execute(array($id));
    $game = $post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

    $gp = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=';
    $html = file_get_html($gp.$game->gp.'&hl=ru');
    $datePublished = $html->find('div[itemprop="datePublished"]');

    if ($datePublished[0]->innertext !== $game->lastupdate){
        // что то
    }
    else{
        // что то
    }
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);
}
```

Потребление памяти скриптом ~1,1 мб. Время выполнения ~50 сек.

Comment: То, что при разборе HTML загружается CPU, является нормальным (логичным) поведением системы. В чем конкретная проблема-то?

Comment: Тем более 50 парсингов одним махом обрабатываете.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, нет как такой проблемы, вопрос лишь о нагрузке CPU, обычно CPU 0-1%, а тут при парсинге поднимается до 68%, сайт при этом работает нормально, но, чем это может быть опасно для системы? Например я планирую выполнять такой запрос каждый день, но уже с `$i<=1000`

Comment: `prepare` делайте один раз перед циклом, а внутри только execute, это конечно почти не повлияет на загрузку, но чуток быстрее будет. И при возможности (если у вас там действительно выборка по диапазону id) может сделать один запрос `id between 1 and 50` и цикл по нему уже

Comment: @emtecif, пожалуйста, прочитайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask . Цитирую: "_Следует задавать исключительно практические вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах_". А раз проблемы нет, то и смысла в вопросе тоже...

Answer (score 1):

Основная причина - работа с DOM. Из-за высокой абстракции, разбор не является тривиальной операцией.
Плюс - `file_get_contents`, так же как и `file_get_html` - жутко медлительные функции. Если не вдаваться в подробности, необходимо отправить `Connection: close` хеадер с запросом:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
file_get_contents("http://www.something.com/somepage.html",false,$context);
```

Но лучшим решение будет использовать [multi curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php). И выбирать не по 1 элементу, а сразу получить все с PDO.